# Create FxCop .ruleset file using free tools

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fxcop

How can I create a .ruleset file for FxCop, using only MSVS 10 Professional edition and free tools such as FxCopIntegrator?

The only graphical tool I found is FxCop GUI which allows to choose rules. That rule selection results in creating a ".fxcop" file. But FxCopIntegrator, while providing ability to specify own rule set, requires another file format (".ruleset")

I've found no way to convert .fxcop files to .ruleset. ".FxCop" contains rule names, ".ruleset" contains numbers like "CA1xxx".

Have I missed some obvious way to do that? Can it be done at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no publicly available tool for coverting .fxcop project files to .ruleset files.  However, .ruleset files are simply xml files, so you can edit them in any text editor.

BTW, FxCopIntegrator does support use of .fxcop files as well, so there's no need to stop using them if you have other reasons to want to do so.